# Multiply matrix by user input

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015, user-input

This is a code sample that multiplies a matrix by a number of user input. The action should be repeated by the number of user input. For example if I put a number 3 I get 3 same printed matrix. Instead I want that matrix is multiplied with number 3 for 3 times (each new matrix is multiplied by number 3). Does anyone have idea how I can do it? Thank you

```
*using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace user_input
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] nodes = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
            int[,] adjmatrix = new int[,]
                    {{2,7,3,8,4},
                     {7,0,8,2,6},
                     {6,8,4,9,7},
                     {8,5,9,8,8},
                     {4,9,7,8,1}
                    };
            int[,] newmatrix = new int[adjmatrix.GetLength(0), adjmatrix.GetLength(1)];
            Printmatrix(adjmatrix, nodes, nodes, "Input Matrix");
            Newline();
            int n = 0;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                MultipliedMatrix(ref newmatrix, adjmatrix, n);
                Newline();
                Printmatrix(newmatrix, nodes, nodes, "Multiplied Matrix");
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void Newline()
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        private static void MultipliedMatrix(ref int[,] newmatrix, int[,] adjmatrix, int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < adjmatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < adjmatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    newmatrix[i, j] = adjmatrix[i, j] * n;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Printmatrix(int[,] adjmatrix, string[] nodes_h, string[] nodes_v, string title)
        {
            if (adjmatrix.GetLength(0) != 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("{0}\n", title);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.Write("\t");
                for (int i = 0; i < adjmatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", nodes_v[i]);
                for (int i = 0; i < adjmatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Newline();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", nodes_h[i]);
                    for (int j = 0; j < adjmatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        if (adjmatrix[i, j] < 500) Console.Write("{0}\t", adjmatrix[i, j]);
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.Write("-\t", adjmatrix[i, j]);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                Newline();
            }
        }
    }
}*
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I would change the multiply to a function instead of void method call, so it looks nicer an then

this would be the pseudocode:

```
n = userinput;
i=0;
int[,] result;

do
  i+=1;
  result = MultiplyMatrix(result, n);
while i<n


int[,] MultiplyMatrix(adjmatrix, n){
   (multiply)  
   return resultMatrix };
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep passing the same matrix as input to `MultipliedMatrix()`, so it keeps doing the same thing.

To make it operate on the new matrix, add the following line immediately after the call to `Printmatrix()` inside the loop:

```
adjmatrix = newmatrix;
```

Alternatively (and better IMO) is to change `MultipliedMatrix()` to return the new matrix, like so:

```
private static int[,] MultipliedMatrix(int[,] adjmatrix, int n)
{
    int[,] newmatrix = new int[adjmatrix.GetLength(0), adjmatrix.GetLength(1)];

    for (int i = 0; i < adjmatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < adjmatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            newmatrix[i, j] = adjmatrix[i, j] * n;

    return newmatrix;
}
```

Then your code in the multiply loop would look like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        adjmatrix = MultipliedMatrix(adjmatrix, n);
        Newline();
        Printmatrix(adjmatrix, nodes, nodes, "Multiplied Matrix");
    }
```

Note that this loses the reference to the original `adjmatrix`, which is not a problem for your current code.

However if you needed to keep the original reference, do it like this:

```
var newMatrix = adjmatrix;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    newMatrix = MultipliedMatrix(newMatrix, n);
    Newline();
    Printmatrix(adjmatrix, nodes, nodes, "Multiplied Matrix");
}
```